# Woodbury matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I want to invert the following matrix:
$$
I_m - B (B^T B)^{-1} B^T
$$
where $B$ is $m \times n$ with $m > n$ and $B$ has full column rank. The [Woodbury matrix inverse identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) states:
$$
(A + UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1} U (C^{-1} + V A^{-1} U)^{-1} V A^{-1}
$$
Now if we identify:
\begin{align}
A &= I_m \\
U &= B \\
C &= -(B^T B)^{-1} \\
V &= B^T
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
(I_m - B (B^T B)^{-1} B^T)^{-1} &= I_m - B (-B^T B + B^T B)^{-1} B^T \end{align}
but this leads to the inverse of a singular matrix. So this seems to indicate that the Woodbury formula won't work on my matrix.

Does anyone know of another way to invert my matrix?

Comment: Are you sure the matrix is invertible?

Comment: Your matrix is not invertible so there is no way to invert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example: let 
\begin{align}
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
B^TB = I_2
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T = BB^T=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
I-B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which is not invertible.

In fact, $P=B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$ is a projection matrix onto the column space of $B$ and $I-P$ projects onto the orthogonal complement.